# Is there anyway to run Final Cut studio 3 on High Sierra?

Tags: macos, macros, final-cut-pro

i have tried to modify the info.plist inside final cut studio app so that it can start under HS and i succeeded . After that it request prokit frameworks , which i have manged to get and installed in /system/library/privateframeworks

the software starts but it ends up with opening only the browser window with out any other windows .

in terminal here what i get:

/Applications/Final\ Cut\ Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/Final\ Cut\ Pro ; exit;

migs-mbp:~ mig$ /Applications/Final\ Cut\ Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/Final\ Cut\ Pro ; exit;

/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.30.2/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:50: Error: unsupported compressor 8

/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.30.2/Libraries/CompressData/CompressData.c:353: Error: Unknown compression scheme encountered for file '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/Exceptions.plist'

/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.30.2/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:50: Error: unsupported compressor 8

/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.30.2/Libraries/CompressData/CompressData.c:353: Error: Unknown compression scheme encountered for file '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library/AppExceptions.bundle/Exceptions.plist'

DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x17da2cd0, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x17d2e330

objc[3210]: Class ImageSequenceMedia is implemented in both /Library/Application

any help would be really appreciated